# SpaCy not assigning proper dependency label when parsing text

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I took some code from [the SpaCy docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training) that allows you to assign custom dependency labels to text, I want to use this to interpret intent from the user. It's mostly working but for example when I run the code it labels "delete" as 'ROOT' where it should label it as 'INTENT' like it shows in the `deps` dictionary.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function

import plac
import random
import spacy
from pathlib import Path


# training data: texts, heads and dependency labels
# for no relation, we simply chose an arbitrary dependency label, e.g. '-'
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("How do I delete my account?", {
        'heads': [3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3],  # index of token head
        'deps': ['ROOT', '-', '-', 'INTENT', '-', 'OBJECT', '-']
    }),
    ("How do I add a balance?", {
        'heads': [3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3],
        'deps': ['ROOT', '-', '-', 'INTENT', '-', 'OBJECT', '-']
    }),
    ("How do I deposit my funds into my bank account?", {
        'heads': [3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 9, 9, 6, 3],
        'deps': ['ROOT', '-', '-', 'INTENT', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'OBJECT', '-']
    }),
    ("How do I fill out feedback forms?", {
        'heads': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3],
        'deps': ['ROOT', '-', '-', 'INTENT', '-', '-', 'OBJECT', '-']
    }),
    #("How does my profile impact my score?", {
        #'heads': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4],
        #'deps': ['ROOT', '-', '-', '-', 'INTENT', '-', 'OBJECT' '-']
    #}),
    ("What are the fees?", {
        'heads': [1, 1, 3, 1, 1],
        'deps': ['ROOT', '-', '-', 'INTENT', '-']
    }),
    ("How do I update my profile picture?", {
        'heads': [3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 3, 3],
        'deps': ['ROOT', '-', '-', 'INTENT', '-', 'OBJECT', 'OBJECT', '-']
    }),
    ("How do I add a referral to the marketplace?", {
        'heads': [3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 8, 6, 3],
        'deps': ['ROOT', '-', '-', 'INTENT', '-', 'OBJECT', '-', '-', 'OBJECT', '-']
    }),


]


@plac.annotations(
    model=("Model name. Defaults to blank 'en' model.", "option", "m", str),
    output_dir=("Optional output directory", "option", "o", Path),
    n_iter=("Number of training iterations", "option", "n", int))
def main(model=None, output_dir=None, n_iter=5):
    """Load the model, set up the pipeline and train the parser."""
    if model is not None:
        nlp = spacy.load(model)  # load existing spaCy model
        print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    else:
        nlp = spacy.blank('en')  # create blank Language class
        print("Created blank 'en' model")

    # We'll use the built-in dependency parser class, but we want to create a
    # fresh instance – just in case.
    if 'parser' in nlp.pipe_names:
        nlp.remove_pipe('parser')
    parser = nlp.create_pipe('parser')
    nlp.add_pipe(parser, first=True)

    #add new labels to the parser
    for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
        for dep in annotations.get('deps', []):
            parser.add_label(dep)

    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'parser']
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train parser
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
        for itn in range(n_iter):
            random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
            losses = {}
            for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
                nlp.update([text], [annotations], sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
            print(losses)

    # test the trained model
    test_model(nlp)

    # save model to output directory
    if output_dir is not None:
        output_dir = Path(output_dir)
        if not output_dir.exists():
            output_dir.mkdir()
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print("Saved model to", output_dir)

        # test the saved model
        print("Loading from", output_dir)
        nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
        test_model(nlp2)


def test_model(nlp):
    texts = ["How do I delete my account?"]
    docs = nlp.pipe(texts)
    for doc in docs:
        print(doc.text)
        print([(t.text, t.dep_, t.head.text) for t in doc if t.dep_ != '-'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plac.call(main)
```

This is the output:
`How do I delete my account?
[(u'How', u'ROOT', u'delete'), (u'delete', u'ROOT', u'delete'), (u'account', u'OBJECT', u'delete')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the origin of your problem is that the root of the dependency tree is automatically labelled as `'ROOT'`,
(and the root of the dependency tree is defined as the token whose head is itself).

A possible workaround consists in adding an artificial root to your training data:

```
("root How do I delete my account?", {
    'heads': [0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 6, 4, 4],  # index of token head
    'deps': ['ROOT', '-', '-', '-', 'INTENT', '-', 'OBJECT', '-']
})
```

(Also add the symbol `root` to your test examples: `texts = ["root How do I delete my account?"]`)

With these changes, if you train the model long enough, you will obtain:

```
root How do I delete my account?
[('root', 'ROOT', 'root'), ('delete', 'INTENT', 'root'), ('account', 'OBJECT', 'delete')]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, that does seem to do the trick. Instead of adding 'root' to the beginning of the text I tried just changing the value of the first index to '0' to see if that would do the same. But it doesn't for some reason, why can I not get it to recognize "How" in this case as the root?

Comment: My guess is that it is not the convention used by spacy: 0 means that the head of the current token is the first of the sentence. (in contrast to the conllu format where 0 indicates the root, and tokens are indexed from 1).

Comment: Edit: I misunderstood, you can make 'How' the root with 0, but then, you should change the head of delete to 'How': `[0, 3, 3, 0, 5, 3, 3]`, otherwise, your tree will have 2 roots.

Comment: Yea just realized that myself, I just ran a piece of code that returns the head of each token in a string. For "How do I delete my account?" "how"   is not it's own head (not the root), "delete" is it's head. However for "root How do I delete my account?" "root" is it's own head, therefore it is the root. Thanks again you're a champ, cheers